# XPathでXMLの要素名に日本語が使われている要素をマッチさせたい

Tags: ruby, xml, xpath

Rubyのバージョンは2.1.2です。

REXMLを使ってXML内の特定のタグ以下のノードにマッチさせたいです。
タグが英語であればマッチするのですが、日本語のタグだとルート以下の全体がマッチしてしまいます。
例えば、XML解析のRubyコードは以下のようになっています。

```
require 'rexml/document'

doc = nil
File.open("example.xml") do |file|
  doc = REXML::Document.new(file)
end

puts REXML::XPath.match(doc, "/root/a")
```

この時、読み込むexample.xmlが以下のような場合は、

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<root>
  <a>
    <b/>
  </a>
  <a>
    <b>bbb1</b>
    <b>bbb2</b>
      <e>eeee1</e>
      <f>ffff1</f>
    <b>bbb3</b>
    <c>ccc1</c>
  </a>
  <a>
    <b>bbb4</b>
    <b>bbb5</b>
  </a>
</root>
```

以下のように返ってきますが、

```
#<a>
#  <b/>
#</a>
#<a>
#  <b>bbb1</b>
#  <b>bbb2</b>
#    <e>eeee1</e>
#    <f>ffff1</f>
#  <b>bbb3</b>
#  <c>ccc1</c>
#</a>
#<a>
#  <b>bbb4</b>
#  <b>bbb5</b>
#</a>
```

example.xmlが以下のような場合、

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<本棚>
  <本>
    <b/>
  </本>
  <本>
    <b>bbb1</b>
    <b>bbb2</b>
      <e>eeee1</e>
      <f>ffff1</f>
    <b>bbb3</b>
    <c>ccc1</c>
  </本>
  <本>
    <b>bbb4</b>
    <b>bbb5</b>
  </本>
</本棚>
```

Rubyのコードを以下のように書き換えても、

```
# coding: utf-8
require 'rexml/document'

doc = nil
File.open("example.xml") do |file|
  doc = REXML::Document.new(file)
end

puts REXML::XPath.match(doc, "/本棚/本")
```

以下のように返ってきます。

```
#<本棚>
#  <本>
#    <b/>
#  </本>
#  <本>
#    <b>bbb1</b>
#    <b>bbb2</b>
#      <e>eeee1</e>
#      <f>ffff1</f>
#    <b>bbb3</b>
#    <c>ccc1</c>
#  </本>
#  <本>
#    <b>bbb4</b>
#    <b>bbb5</b>
#  </本>
#</本棚>
```

理想は以下のように返ってきて欲しいです。

```
#<本>
#  <b/>
#</本>
#<本>
#  <b>bbb1</b>
#  <b>bbb2</b>
#    <e>eeee1</e>
#    <f>ffff1</f>
#  <b>bbb3</b>
#  <c>ccc1</c>
#</本>
#<本>
#  <b>bbb4</b>
#  <b>bbb5</b>
#</本>
```

XMLファイル自体の文字コードはUTF-8です。
どのようにしたら希望通りにパースされた結果を得ることができるでしょうか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

nokogiriでもよろしければ

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = nil
File.open("example.xml") do |file|
   doc = Nokogiri::XML(file)
end

puts doc.xpath("/本棚/本")
```

で、以下の様に取得できました。

```
<本>
    <b/>
    </本>
<本>
      <b>bbb1</b>
      <b>bbb2</b>
      <e>eeee1</e>
      <f>ffff1</f>
      <b>bbb3</b>
      <c>ccc1</c>
    </本>
<本>
      <b>bbb4</b>
      <b>bbb5</b>
    </本>
```

以下の環境で確認しました

- windows 7 + ruby 2.1.4 + nokogiri 1.6.5
- Ubuntu 14.04 + ruby 2.1.5 + nokogiri 1.6.5
  ( ruby2.1-dev, libxml2, libxml2-dev, libxslt1.1, libxslt1-dev )

---

### 補足の追記:

いきなりnokogoriを提案した形になってしまったので少し補足します。
ubuntuやwindows上でもREXMLでは"/本棚/本"が "/本棚" と同じ動きになっていました。
また、"/山/川"などとしても同様に"/山"と同じ様な動作でしたのでnokogiriで試してみたら上手くいったので提案しました。

ruby 1.8をつかって日本語でも正しく区切られるようなページを見かけていたため、先ほど気になって試してみましたが、windows環境でrubyinstallerからruby 1.8.7を入れて質問のrexmlで"/本棚/本"のソースそのままで試したところ以下の様に取得されました。
※ 1.8.7でコマンドプロンプト上で実行するとコマンドプロンプトがutf8をプリントできずに`本`が`<譛ｬ>`と化けてしまいますが、ファイルにリダイレクトすればutf8の文字コードで以下の内容になっています。

```
<本>
    <b/>
    </本>
<本>
      <b>bbb1</b>
      <b>bbb2</b>
      <e>eeee1</e>
      <f>ffff1</f>
      <b>bbb3</b>
      <c>ccc1</c>
    </本>
<本>
      <b>bbb4</b>
      <b>bbb5</b>
    </本>
```

問題は Win/Linuxどちらでも起きているので、rubyかREXMLかどちらかのバージョンの問題と思われます。

Comment: なるほど。今回はRuby2.1ということと、タイトルに「REXMLで」と書きましたが、スクレイピングできれば問題ないので、NokogiriでOKでした。
ありがとうございました！